# How to define a default value for a get parameters with Django?

Tags: django

I do not understand why I cannot define a default value for a get parameter even after reading the document about QueryDict.
This is what I have:

```
def find_users(request):

    selected_zipcode = request.GET.get('zipcode', 75000)
    selected_service = request.GET.get('service', 1)

    # raise Exception(request.GET)

    users = User.objects.filter(
        Q(zipcode=selected_zipcode),
        Q(proposals__pk=selected_service)
    )
    return render(
        request,
        'users.html', {users
        'users': pet_sitters,
    })
```

I can get my parameter if set in my url but if I do not define a zipcode parameter, i do not get **75000** as value. I only have 75000 if zipcode parameter does not exists.

Comment: Please give more details about the context: what kind of models, views, forms or whatever did you create, so we understand how this lonely line of code is integrated

Comment: Was it set as an empty string, like `?zipcode`, or `?zipcode=`?

Comment: @sbm54: can you share the URL of the HTTP request you made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that you wrote the querystring as `?zipcode`, or as `?zipcode=`. In that case the key *is* set and maps on the empty string.

You can set another value in that case by implementing this as:

```
selected_zipcode = request.GET.get('zipcode', 75000) or 75000
```

This will in case the result of `request.GET.get(…)` has truthiness `False`, return the second operand so `75000`.

It might however be better to work with a form, and pass the `request.GET` as data, so:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    zipcode = forms.IntegerField(initial=75000, required=False)
    service = form.IntegerField(initial=1, required=False)
```

and work in the view with:

```
def find_users(request):
    form = MyForm(request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        selected_zipcode = myform.cleaned_data['zipcode']
        selected_service = myform.cleaned_data['service']
        # …
    # …
```